# Populating Data Extension Column from Existing Columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I would like to populate a Data Extension Column from existing columns

Say I have a Data Extension Like this

FN |  LN | FN LN
Jack|Johns| Null
Jane|Jones| Null
Luke|Smith| Null

FN and LN are already populated in the Data Extension and Column 3 (FN LN) has null values. I am unsure what query to write to so that Data Extension can be populated as follows

FN |  LN | FN LN
Jack|Johns| Jack&johns
Jane|Jones| Jane&Jones
Luke|Smith| Luke&Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do either concat() or use the '+'.

Sample:

```
SELECT FN
, LN
, concat(FN,'&',LN) as [FN LN]
FROM myDE
```

OR

```
SELECT FN
, LN
, FN + '&' + LN as [FN LN]
```